# How to use artifacts for dotnet test

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, artifact, dotnet-build

I would like to use the artifacts from my build stage for the test stage. But somehow the `dotnet test` command does not find any tests and instantly exits.

The `dotnet restore` & `dotnet build` command seem to work differently depending on whether executed locally or in the CI.

My `.gitlab-ci`:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

variables:
  CONFIGURATION: 'Release'
  MSBUILDDISABLENODEREUSE: "1"
  TEST_RESULT_DIRECTORY: '.test-results'

default:
  tags:
    - .NET 6.0
    - WPF

stages:
  - Build
  - Test

Build:
  stage: Build
  script:
    - dotnet restore --no-cache
    - dotnet build --no-restore --configuration $CONFIGURATION
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./**/bin/Release
      - ./**/obj/Release
    expire_in: 1 day

Test:
  stage: Test
  needs:
    - job: Build
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - dotnet test --no-build --nologo --configuration $CONFIGURATION --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=../$TEST_RESULT_DIRECTORY/{assembly}.xml;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: 
        - ./$TEST_RESULT_DIRECTORY/*.xml
```

Maybe I'm just missing a critical file in the artifacts, but by comparing the local and CI generated files I noticed just a difference in additional NuGet related files on local generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found out that not all files which are needed for `dotnet test` are put in the `obj/Release` folder. Some of them are one level above.

The solution is to include the full `obj` directory.

```
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./**/bin/Release
      - ./**/obj
```